# AutoCompleteTextView: Suggest new completions after a suggestion is selected

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

My `AutoCompleteTextView` is kind of "word-based". Suppose a valid completion would be:

This is a valid phrase.

When the user enters "T", I don't want to suggest the whole phrase immediately. Rather I want to suggesst only "This ".

Next, when the input is "This ", the next suggestion is "This is ", and so on.

This works fine as long as I type in every letter manually. However, if instead of typing everything I select "This " from the drop down, the drop down disappears and won't suggest the follow-up.

I tried with `addTextChangedListener()`, `setOnClickListener()` and `setOnItemSelectedListener()`, but that didn't help.

Has anyone achieved this before?

Comment: I think that dropdown is based on whether it has focus or not.  I would try giving the edit text focus again once the item is selected.

Comment: No, that didn't do it :-(

Comment: @user805623 I know it's like 9 months later, but did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Not really. I am using a workaround: The user selects a word in the autocomplete dropdown and must then enter a space character manually before completions are updated. If you find out something better, please do let me know!!